# Problems with Bootstrap: Navbar collapse on small screens ( mobile) does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the bootstrap navigation bar. I want to collapse the elements into
Currently the navbar looks like this on mobile, as I would expect it: [current state before clicking on the hamburger icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwtDk.png)

After clicking on the Hamburger icon, it just went black.
Currently the code is:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--my script-->
    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Katholische Jugend Maudach</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" role="navigation">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">
                <img src="../images/Logo.png" height="60px" width="60px" />
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                      <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="activities.html">Topic 2</a>
                     </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="downloads.html">Topic 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">Topic 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="quiz.html">Topic 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="impressum.html">Topic 5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="sendMail()">Contakt</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>

</nav>
</div>
</body>
```

After clicking the hamburger icon the following happens. It just went black and only the button is shown.

[after clicking the hamburger icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6NL7.png)

Some further information besides the code:

- I had a problem with CORS and added CORS Everywhere.
- currently the code is not deployed on a server. Just HTML files displayed in the browser
- The navbar is loaded with `onload`  dynamically into the webpage with **jquery** (If the navbar changes, I have to alter just one file)

If I should provide further information, please let me know.

Any hints are appreciated and thanks for your time.

Comment: I've put your code into a snippet, and as you can see it is working. If you are having problems, they are being caused somewhere else in code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: My CSS stylesheet is causing problems. So I removed it and everythings works fine

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be placing your script CDNs at the end of the body, that too in a particular order. Something like this:

```
. . .
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

I am not sure if this will help. Try this once.

Comment: My stylesheet is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working and the problem is in my custom CSS Stylesheet.